# CacheManager in Guava

Tags: java, caching, guava, javax

In javax caching,

> A [CacheManager](https://static.javadoc.io/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/CacheManager.html) provides a means of establishing, configuring,
>   acquiring, closing and destroying uniquely named Caches.

I would like to use the [guava caching](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) because of it's speed and usefullness, but I don't find a similar `CacheManager` in guava cache. How can I achieve the functionality of a `CacheManager` if I am to use `LoadingCache` from guava?
The obvious way would be to write our own `CacheManager` implementation, but is there a better option? Note that I am not using Spring.

Comment: Guava has CacheBuilders: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: This is a little too vague. What *specific* functionally are you looking for?

Comment: Yes it has a CacheBuilder, but not  a CacheManager

Comment: I would like to use the same cache in different objects. Each cache must be identifiable by a given id. I would like to achieve the functionality of  a CacheManager https://static.javadoc.io/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/CacheManager.html

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), a Guava cache rewrite, has JCache support. However it is not strongly recommended due to design flaws in the jsr that make it a poor development experience for real world applications.

Comment: I guess, you can get this easily by wrapping your cache in a three line class and using dependency injection: `@Singleton class MyBlueCacheHolder { public final Cache<...> cache = ....; }`. Or a standard singleton (which is evil) or anything what you use for other classes. IMHO caches are just like other objects and I can't see a need for a specialized manager. Especially not for Guava cache which has no close method (and doesn't need to be closed).